# Android aws sdk cognito auth app gets crash while Login

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are using android aws cognito a
Sdk and with login getting exceptio

I  Creating the AWSKeyValueStore with key for sharedPreferencesForData = CognitoIdentityProviderCache

E  com.amazonaws.internal.keyvaluestore.KeyNotFoundException: Error occurred while accessing AndroidKeyStore to retrieve the key for keyAlias: CognitoIdentityProviderCache.aesKeyStoreAlias

I  Deleting the encryption key identified by the keyAlias: CognitoIdentityProviderCache.aesKeyStoreAlias
2023-08-16 18:45:51.740 17078-17078 AWSKeyValueStore                   E  Error in retrieving the decryption key used to decrypt the data from the persistent store. Returning null for the requested dataKey = CognitoIdentityProvider.000000.LastAuthUser
2023-08-16 18:45:51.760 17078-17078 AWSKeyValueStore                  E  com.amazonaws.internal.keyvaluestore.KeyNotFoundException: Error occurred while accessing AndroidKeyStore to retrieve the key for keyAlias: CognitoIdentityProviderCache.aesKeyStoreAlias
2023-08-16 18:45:51.760 17078-17078 AWSKeyValueStore            I  Deleting the encryption key identified by the keyAlias: CognitoIdentityProviderCache.aesKeyStoreAlias
2023-08-16 18:45:51.764 17078-17078 AWSKeyValueStore                 W  No encryption key found for encryptionKeyAlias: CognitoIdentityProviderCache.aesKeyStoreAlias
2023-08-16 18:45:51.786 17078-17078 KeyProvider23                  I  Generated the encryption key identified by the keyAlias: CognitoIdentityProviderCache.aesKeyStoreAlias using AndroidKeyStore
2023-08-16 18:45:51.803 17078-17078 KeyProvider23                    D  AndroidKeyStore contains keyAlias CognitoIdentityProviderCache.aesKeyStoreAlias